# Need help debugging "Internal server error" on heroku app caused by "JSON serializable"

Tags: python, json, serialization, heroku, flask

So I'm writing a RESTful API for Hacker News. Up until yesterday it was working just fine. When I deployed with some changes, everything was fine. But suddenly it's throwing 500 errors like crazy.

```
http://hnify.herokuapp.com/get/top - throws 500
http://hnify.herokuapp.com/get/newest - throws 500
http://hnify.herokuapp.com/get/best - throws 500
```

but, `http://hnify.herokuapp.com/get/trends` does not throw any errors and works flawlessly.

*Addendum: While writing this question, the `trends` URL also started throwing the 500 error.*

Here's a partial `heroku logs` result:

```
2013-12-22T17:40:54.528521+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-12-22T17:40:57.323574+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-12-22T17:40:57.826384+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2013-12-22T17:40:57.952472+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-12-22 17:40:57 [2] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2013-12-22T17:40:57.951784+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-12-22 17:40:57 [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2013-12-22T17:40:57.958557+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-12-22 17:40:57 [2] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2013-12-22T17:40:58.831301+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-12-22 17:40:58 [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2013-12-22T17:40:58.830659+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-12-22 17:40:58 [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2013-12-22T17:40:58.831219+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-12-22 17:40:58 [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:12219 (2)
2013-12-22T17:40:58.838520+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-12-22 17:40:58 [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2013-12-22T17:40:59.033671+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-12-22T17:40:59.232862+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2013-12-22T17:41:32.146515+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/get/top host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="71.231.57.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=344ms status=503 bytes=72
2013-12-22T17:53:44.759150+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/get/newest host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="71.231.57.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=328ms status=503 bytes=72
2013-12-22T17:54:07.674549+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/get/trends host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="71.231.57.36" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=7056ms status=200 bytes=2121
2013-12-22T18:18:36.120842+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/get/trends host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="71.231.57.36" dyno=web.1 connect=81ms service=35ms status=503 bytes=72
2013-12-22T18:18:43.977936+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/main.css host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="71.231.57.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=72
2013-12-22T18:18:43.661406+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="71.231.57.36" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=2927
2013-12-22T18:18:47.605158+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/get/top host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="71.231.57.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=503 bytes=72
2013-12-22T18:18:40.786325+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/get/ host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="71.231.57.36" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=72
2013-12-22T18:26:52.188789+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/best host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="216.46.175.33, 10.179.81.114, 54.241.198.78" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=2706ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:26:52.189318+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/newest host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="216.46.175.37, 10.179.81.114, 184.169.203.101" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2707ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:26:52.190210+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/trends host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="216.46.190.190, 10.196.6.45, 50.18.102.132" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=633ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:26:53.569138+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/best host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="216.46.175.36, 10.196.6.45, 54.241.198.78" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=1981ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:26:49.478860+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/top host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="216.46.175.34, 10.179.81.114, 184.169.203.101" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=4ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:27:35.846872+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/top host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="182.50.130.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:27:36.343779+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/get/top host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="182.50.130.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=503 bytes=72
2013-12-22T18:27:36.919042+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/newest host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="182.50.130.85" dyno=web.1 connect=10ms service=21ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:27:42.167121+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/get/trends host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="182.50.130.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=503 bytes=72
2013-12-22T18:27:50.385923+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/top host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="182.50.130.85" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=7ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:27:50.955337+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/newest host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="182.50.130.85" dyno=web.1 connect=11ms service=9ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:27:53.414690+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/trends host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="182.50.130.85" dyno=web.1 connect=18ms service=27ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:27:52.794785+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/best host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="182.50.130.85" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=1276ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:28:31.135251+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/get/top host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="46.236.24.52" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=503 bytes=72
2013-12-22T18:28:31.469293+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/get/newest host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="46.236.24.52" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=503 bytes=72
2013-12-22T18:28:32.898799+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/get/best host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="46.236.24.52" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1152ms status=503 bytes=72
2013-12-22T18:26:52.191781+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/newest host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="216.46.175.36, 10.196.6.45, 184.169.203.101" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=714ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:27:37.443588+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/get/newest host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="182.50.130.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=503 bytes=72
2013-12-22T18:27:41.142385+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/get/best host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="182.50.130.85" dyno=web.1 connect=8ms service=1294ms status=503 bytes=72
2013-12-22T18:27:39.233665+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/best host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="182.50.130.85" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=1262ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:29:56.874183+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/top host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="185.2.29.4" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:29:57.292349+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/newest host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="185.2.29.4" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=5ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:29:57.478167+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/get/newest host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="185.2.29.4" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=503 bytes=72
2013-12-22T18:29:58.972529+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/best host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="185.2.29.4" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1302ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:30:00.688709+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/trends host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="185.2.29.4" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=4ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:30:00.885436+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/get/trends host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="185.2.29.4" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=503 bytes=72
2013-12-22T18:30:21.017547+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/newest host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="185.2.29.4" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=39ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:30:20.760432+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/top host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="185.2.29.4" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=6ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:30:22.593351+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/trends host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="185.2.29.4" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-12-22T18:29:57.084468+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/get/top host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="185.2.29.4" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=503 bytes=72
2013-12-22T18:30:22.401968+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/get/best host=hnify.herokuapp.com fwd="185.2.29.4" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=1177ms status=503 bytes=0
```

In my [most recent change to the code](https://github.com/karan/HNify/commit/fc7369920fd52aafa27c254553c503b58c831882), I did not even touch the calls that now throw the error.

After a lot of printing and returning, I found that the core of the issue is this:

```
return jsonify(temp_cache['top']['response_json'])
```

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/karan/Desktop/Dropbox/Codebase/General/envs/hnify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/karan/Desktop/Dropbox/Codebase/General/envs/hnify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Users/karan/Desktop/Dropbox/Codebase/General/envs/hnify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/karan/Desktop/Dropbox/Codebase/General/envs/hnify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/karan/Desktop/Dropbox/Codebase/General/envs/hnify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/karan/Desktop/Dropbox/Codebase/General/envs/hnify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/karan/Desktop/Dropbox/Codebase/General/envs/hnify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/karan/Desktop/Dropbox/Codebase/General/envs/hnify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/karan/Desktop/Dropbox/Codebase/General/envs/hnify/HNify/app.py", line 67, in get_top
    return jsonify(temp_cache['top']['response_json'])
  File "/Users/karan/Desktop/Dropbox/Codebase/General/envs/hnify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 238, in jsonify
    indent=indent),
  File "/Users/karan/Desktop/Dropbox/Codebase/General/envs/hnify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 126, in dumps
    rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 250, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 209, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 434, in _iterencode
    for chunk in _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 408, in _iterencode_dict
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 332, in _iterencode_list
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 442, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/Users/karan/Desktop/Dropbox/Codebase/General/envs/hnify/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 83, in default
    return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <Story: ID=6950891> is not JSON serializable
```

On researching about this, I found that the error can be caused by passing a non`dict` type to `jsonify`). However, in my case that's not true:

```
>>> type(temp_cache['top']['response_json'])
<type 'dict'>
```

I tried returning a `jsonify`ed list instead of a `dict` but that gives the same error. Complete code for the app is [here](https://github.com/karan/HNify/blob/master/app.py)

Can someone point out what's wrong?

Comment: I serve my own stuff rather than use something like Heroku so this may not apply, but these weird problems are almost always because I need to restart the web server. Also, now's a good time to add functional and unit tests to your app's deployment script to avoid this kind of thing.

Comment: @GarryCairns I did restart the server before posting the question. Guess I should have posted that. As for unit tests, I'm using a library I wrote which does that unittests. Anyhow, I will try and write tests here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On researching about this, I found that the error can be caused by passing a nondict type to jsonify

This is not completely accurate. Not only the top level object must be a dict, but any referenced objects as well. The stack trace indicates that you have an object of class `Story` referenced by the top-level dict.

It looks like in `get_top()` you assign this to your cache:

```
temp_cache['top']['response_json'] = {'stories': hn.get_stories()}
```

You need to add a function that converts a `Story` object into a dictionary, and then the problem should go away.

Also, from your description it seems it was costly for you to find the location of the error. Consider adding an email logger that is activated in production mode on Heroku. That way each time there is an error you'll get the stack trace by email.

Good luck.

Comment: I love you, in a non-gay way!